# MySQL, PHP Relative search results / Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I understand LIKE results with wildcards etc.  What I need to know is a good way to get search results with the most relative at the top.

For Example:
I search for "Front Brake CarModel" or something similar.

Currently I explode the string by spaces and create an addition OR/WHERE state so the query would look something like this .

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE article_text LIKE '%Front%' OR article_text LIKE '%Brake%' OR article_text LIKE '%CarModel%'
```

Due to my novice searching skills, this is not great as it get results for every word in the search term.  What I would like to happen is get the result and sort with the articles with the most found words at the top.  If that makes sense.

Advice?

EDIT :  Table is type InnoDB and cannot change type due to foreign key restraints.  Thus removing the ability for me to use FULLTEXT indexing :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Full Text search the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614358/is-full-text-search-the-answer)

Comment: @MarcusAdams Unfortunately not.  My table is InnoDB and cannot change the type.  So I cannot use FULLTEXT indexing.

Comment: So why not just create a new table with just the search text, and a key into the "real" table as MyIASM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with a fulltext index.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `ft_search` (`article_text`);

SELECT *, MATCH(article_text) AGAINST('Front Brake CarModel') AS score
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(article_text) AGAINST('Front Brake CarModel') ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: This looks promising however it appears the table I am using doesn't support FULLTEXT indexing.  "The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes"

Comment: You are not using the MyISAM engine. Most likely your table is InnoDB. Use `ALTER TABLE table ENGINE=MyISAM` to change engine and try again.

Comment: If you are using innodb tables then rather than changing the table to myisam, I usually move only the columns I need for the fulltext index to a separate myisam table.