# How can I filter my MySQL results by their content? i.e. if contains hashtags

Tags: php, mysql, hashtag

Just want to know how I can filter out a result using mysql if the "content" field contains a hashtag.

e.g. If a result content is: "#Euro2012 is going to be awesome"

I would not have this returned in my MySQL results....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For varchar fields you can use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myVarCharField NOT LIKE '%#Euro2012%'
```

For text fields you'll need to look into [full-text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614358/is-full-text-search-the-answer).

**Update (Suggested by comments):**

Regular Expression Solution:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myVarCharField NOT RLIKE '#.*\s'
```

If you want to filter by fields that begin with a hashtag add `^` to the regular expression.

Comment: The thing Is It must be dynamic, I won't know what the hashtag is... So something like a regular expression?

Comment: @AndréFigueira: There's [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html).

Comment: You should probably add NOT in front of LIKE, since we don't want to see anything containing hashtag

Comment: to make it filter out, use `NOT LIKE`

Comment: @MikeB I would only know that it starts with a hashtag and would end in a space.

Comment: @MikeB Thanks, but that only got rid of a few of the results, there are still several which did not get remove from the results.

Comment: @AndréFigueira What do the missed results look like?

Comment: Hi Mike I have fiddled with it using REGEX this seems to work:

    SELECT * 
    FROM status 
    WHERE content NOT RLIKE '#[0-9a-zA-Z]'

Comment: @AndréFigueira That expression wouldn't match *"hashtag and would end in a space"*. If the space is optional you can use `#.*\s?`

Answer (score 4):

Using a `regex` and `preg_match_all()`, you could have something like this :

```
$str = <<<STR
this is a string
with a #tag and
another #hello one
STR;

$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches)) {
  var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Which gives the following output :

```
array
  0 => string 'tag' (length=3)
  1 => string 'hello' (length=5)
```

And, if you need to do a bit more manipulations on those, you should take a look at the PCRE Functions section of the manual : there are some others that might help you.